# Retrofit - pass two parameters

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

Link: `"www.example.com/getnewcar/?car[color]={colorOfCar}&car[price]={priceOfCar}"`

```
@GET(...)
fun getNewCar(
            @Query("car[color]") color: String,
            @Query("car[price]") price: String,
            ...
    ): Single<JSONApiObject>
```

I call this function like: `b.getNewCar(carColor, carPrice)`

URL query string ".." must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query. What am I doing wrong? I looked at docs and they suggest using @Query. Can't find what's off tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Query` automatically generates the query part of the URL, so your `@GET` annotation should not include it.

Instead of `@GET("www.example.com/getnewcar/?car[color]={colorOfCar}&car[price]={priceOfCar}")` it should just be `@GET("www.example.com/getnewcar/")`.